# IBM Worklight - Deploy all adapters at once

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

I have total 35 (and increasing) Worklight Adapters in my Worklight Hybrid App.
Now every time I power on my Mac, I need to deploy all those work light adapters **ONE-BY-ONE**

Is there any method by which I can deploy awl the adapters in single shot. As of now, I am unable to find out the way.

Anyone else faced the similar problem?

I am using:
*Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2

Build id: 20130225-0426*
If that matters.

Comment: What is your Worklight version? Also, after you power on the computer, open Eclipse and start the Worklight Development Server, and then visit Worklight Console, the apps and adapters are not available? I find it highly unlikely that you will need to re-deploy all of your adapters...

Comment: What I actually asked is, Is there any way that I can start all adapters in one go? Will try what you suggested though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Deploy All Adapters` action is not available in Worklight Studio, but sounds like a rather useful feature for cases like yours. Feel free [to submit a feature request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).

After you power on the computer, open Eclipse and start the Worklight Development Server, and then visit Worklight Console, the apps and adapters are not available? I find it highly unlikely that you will need to re-deploy all of your adapters...

A possible workaround for it will be to enhance the Ant script that deploys apps and adapters, to  [deploy them all using a loop](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html). Also see:

- [Ant tasks for building and deploying applications and adapters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_for_building.html)

Comment: It worked the way you mentioned in your comment. But I will submit a feature request.

Comment: @IdanAder Got new problem. I want to deploy IBM Worklight App to Apache Tomcat Server. I have deployed .war & .wlapp file(s) and then I need to upload .adapter file for each Adapter I have written.
Two Questions:  
1. **Any way to generate .adapter files for all the adapters?**
2. **Any way to bulk upload those file to my App Server?**

Comment: See my suggestion in the answer - enhance the provided Ant scripts to build and deploy all of your adapters. In a production environment it is the role of the IT department to devise appropriate solutions on their own custom environment.